# A general definition for a character of a (not necessarily associative) algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, lie-algebras, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a algebra over a algebraically closed field $k$. Is there certain definition of a "*character*" $f: A \rightarrow k$?  That is, what is the common and useful condition for a linear map $f: A \rightarrow k$ to be a "*character*" such that the representation theory of $A$ is well-developed via the analysis $f$? Thanks very much!

Comment: If $M$ is a finite-dimensional (left) $A$-module then we can define $\chi_M \colon A \to k$, $a \mapsto \mathrm{tr}(m \mapsto a.m)$. This satisfies many properties that we are used to from the characters of finite-dimensional representations of groups.

Comment: What do you mean by "the representation theory of $A$"?  What is a representation of a nonassociative algebra?

Comment: @Eric: it's an abelian group $M$ and a map $A \otimes M \to M$ satisfying no axioms. Not a very interesting thing to consider.

Comment: So with that definition, the representation theory of $A$ doesn't actually depend on the multiplication of $A$ at all...

Comment: Yeah, man, I'm not the one who decided nonassociative algebras in full generality were worth studying.

Comment: For  more information see this [MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21152/do-non-associative-objects-have-a-natural-notion-of-representation) of Qiaochu Yuan.